# Can I forward an email without a recipient?

Tags: email, yahoo-mail

I seem to have somehow forwarded an email to myself, but there's no recipient!

I don't understand what I did, and I can't replicate the behavior.

Does anyone know what's going on?

This is not a case of BCC. With forwarding via BCC, in the body of the message, you get:

```
----- Forwarded Message -----
From: "myname" <xxx@yahoo.com>
To:
```

Where 'xxx' is my email address, and `To:` field is blank.

In this case, the body contains:

```
 ----- Forwarded Message -----
    From: "sender" <sender@gmail.com>
    To: "differentname" <xxx@yahoo.com>
```

Where 'sender' is the original sender, and 'differentname' is my name **as it appears in the sender's contact list**. (It is not the same as 'myname' from the BCC, which is my name as it appears in my contacts.)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce the behavior, though I'm still unsure what's going through Yahoo!'s code.

To Forward the original, unmarked, message, do the following (tested on the Android Yahoo! Mail app):

Select Forward, then back out. This will create a draft of the Forwarded (but still unsent) message. Now go to the Drafts folder, where the drafted Forward will appear as a reply. Now open the message thread, and select Move. Choose to Move to Inbox, or another folder. The app will not always perform the move. Keep trying. You may have to select the original message.

Eventually, the entire thread will Move out of Drafts. Now your draft has become a real message, in your Inbox! The message was never actually sent, so it has no recipients. The subject line contains only a sender ('Me'). But the body still contains the original header, with the recipient's name as it would appear to the sender.

Interesting. [image]